# How to make an automatic cut when a specific pixel changes color? (Premiere or AE)

Tags: premiere, after-effects, automation

I want to cut between 2 videos when a specific visual change occurs in the current clip. But since the videos are too long I can't do it manually.

Is there a way to make an automatic cut? Or at least somehow mark it on the timeline? When a specific text or popup appears in a specific spot in the video? So somehow track when a pixel changes color?

Comment: To make an actual cut would require scripting. Are you good with Javascript? Otherwise, if you want to control a property like Opacity you could link it with an expression.

Comment: I think you'd do yourself a favor by using davinci resolve's cut-detector. For shot-reshot situations, it should work like a charm. You can then export the edit as xml or aaf and import into premiere/ae again. Davinci Resolve comes with a free version that is capable of all that.

Comment: stib: I think it should be something I can see on the timeline in order to make changes to it. So opacity probably wouldn't work.
I don't know JS but have friends who know JS for web development. Would that work?

Florian Claassen: I'll have to try that. Last time I tried Davinci Resolve, it just stopped working alltogether.

Comment: If your friends have the time and willingness to study the Premiere API, then it's doable. Not a small task though.